# Searching for functions by type signature & return value

Tags: plugins, editor

I was in the shower just now and I thought: it would be cool to be able to search for appropriate functions by their type *and* return value with a given set of appropriate arguments. Consider,

I'm writing some code in VSCode, for example, and I have a string `a` and an object `o` like `{ name: string }`. I want to do something like, join the string and the object's name, maybe with `,` as a delimiter. I am in some big codebase and I have no idea if such a function exists, or what it would be called if it did. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I type

```
fn(a, o): string
```

and a dropdown menu appears with a list of every function in the codebase of the form `string -> { name: string } -> string`, along with the return value of that function given my particular `a` and `o`. So with `a = "hello"` and `o = { name: "Bob" }`, in the list I might see,

```
greet(greeting, user) -> "Hello, Bob"
```

and then if I clicked this, the `fn` I had typed above would autocomplete to `greet`.

I think this would greatly improve, for example, discoverability of common helpers in large codebases. You could maybe configure it with a few folders, and make sure none of those functions had side-effects.

Does this exist somewhere as a plugin? For any language, I'm not picky. I'm aware of [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). This would be like, Hoogle but with return values.